# How to check if a form in a modal is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a bootstrap modal that has a form.  I use am using the jquery.validate library to perform the actual validation on the form.

That part appears to be working correctly. 
However my next step is to take the data from the form and submit to the DB.

Is it better to do this client side or server side and how do I check in either scenario that the form was actually valid?

My modal looks like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new gizmo</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
                    <form role="form" id="newGizmoForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="gizmoName">Gizmo Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gizmoName" name="gizmoName" placeholder="Enter gizmo name" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="action">Action:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" placeholder="Enter action" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveGizmoAdd" style="margin-right:10px"                               >Save</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseGizmoAdd" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>                    
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried server side but the Page.IsValid is always true.
I also tried client side but I get an error "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'form' of undefined or null reference".

```
 $("#btnSaveGizmoAdd").on("click", function () {
        var vStatus = $("#newGizmoForm").valid();

        // Check if form validated.
          // If valid post data to client      
    });
```

Comment: Server side validation is always mandatory, validate the incoming post request with PHP and then insert it into the database after validation

Comment: Client side validation is good as a quick sanity check before submitting to the server. Server side is mandatory, because client side validation can be skipped by people messing with your site, or submitting directly to your endpoint.

Comment: Is there a flag that I can use to verify that validation completed client side, or should I just write code server side checking each field myself and cancelling leaving the modal open should the validation fail?

Comment: How would I go about accessing the data submitted back to me?  Would I need to add "runat='server'" to all of my controls in that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ansewer your first question : You should allways validate your form data on server side, also if you have validated it on client side.
For me your problem is that : when you create your listener on click function, you form doesn't exist in the dom.
Maybe you can try this.
var $form = $(this).parents('form');
var vstatus = $form.valid();

Comment: That didn't work for me.  When is debug vstatus was true (which shouldn't have been since I didnt enter any data), and then I received a bunch of JS null ref errors.

Comment: I checked the DOM and that form doesnt exist.

Comment: you can pu a javascript  event listener on your button and pass your button: 
onclick="doSomthing(this);"
in your javascript you will get your button element. with that element you can navigate to its parent form.
function dosomething(element){
}

Comment: onclick="doSomthing(this);"
in your javascript you will get your button element. with that element you can navigate to its parent form.
function doSomething(element){
  var form = $(element).parents(form);
 console.log(form); // try it to see if your form is here. 
}
make sure your javascript function is NOT inside $(document).ready(function(){...});